# Converting military time to Standard and Universal time in Java?

Tags: java, time

I'm currently getting the correct military time. What I'd like the program to display is something like 4:20:01 instead of 16:20:01 for standard time. I've tried using if statements, but I haven't been successful.

I'm confused on Universal time. Would the Universal Time be the same as the military time? Or is it a separate thing? If so, how can I get the program to show the universal time?

This is the current code I have:

```
package readtime;

import java.time.LocalDateTime; 

public class Time
{
    // field data
    int hour; 
    int minute;
    int second;

    public Time ()
    {
        hour = 0;
        minute = 0;
        second = 0; 
    }

    public void getMilitaryTime()
    {
      LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(); 
      hour = now.getHour(); 
      minute = now.getMinute();
      second = now.getSecond();

      //System.out.print(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second); 
    }

    public void getStandardTime()
    {

    }


    public void getUniversalTime()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return ("Time: " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);
    }

}
```

Comment: "Universal Time" is, basically, what time it is in London (or what time it would be in London if they didn't observe Summer Time).  It has nothing to do with the format in which you display the time.  Aside from reading up on date formats, you should also read up on time zones.

Comment: Universal, or more correctly, Universal Coordinated Time (UTC), _is_ the standard time. Each time zone has what's called "local" time. What you call "military" time is not the exclusive province of the military but is standard throughout most of the world to represent local time. So your "military" time is actually "standard local time" most places. What a time zone refers to as "standard" time is unrelated to 12- or 24-hour representation but to offset from UTC, which changes with time of year in many places. Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) is approximately the same as UTC.

Comment: It's standard to refer to the UTC/GMT standard time in 24-hour format.

Comment: These helped a lot and make sense. I've got it now.

Comment: No, @Marvin, please don’t look there. When you can and even do use `java.time.LocalDateTime`, you both can and should certainly avoid `DateFormat` and its long outdated friends. For formatting you need a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Comment: There are no more different in Military time and normal time, Military time is 24 hour and normal time 12 hour. Indian railway system also following Military time. You can check it's complete [chart](http://www.militarytime.site/). Thanks [military time with normal time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1jMs.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Universal time (also know as UTC for Universal Time Coordinates) and military time are orthogonal concepts. Or independent, if you like.

As I understand [Military time](http://militarytimechart.com) it just means using a 24 hour clock, which is what great parts of the world is doing anyway. So this is what you already have: 16:20:01 (I don’t think your program prints 01 with a leading zero, though). As it stands, it may mean 16:20:01 in your local time zone or 16:20:01 in UTC (or 16:20:01 in some other time zone). I have sometimes seen military time written with four digits and no colon: `1620` and even heard it pronounced “one thousand six hundred and twenty”.

If you intended to populate your fields `hour`, `minute` and `second` with either local or universal and either 12 hour or 24 hour clock times, I would discourage that. It’s generally considered a good idea to keep the data (here the time) and the presentation of data to the user (here a string like 4:20:01) as separate things in your program. So my suggestion is you store the time in one way always and then format it differently depending on the current need. I am sorry, this may render your `Time` class superfluous.

For displaying a time in some desired format it’s easiest to use a `DateTimeFormatter`. To print the current time as something like `4:20:01`:

```
    System.out.println(LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm:ss")));
```

`ZoneId.systemDefault()` is not technically needed, but it makes explicit that you are printing the time in the JVM’s default time zone, so I prefer to have it in.

To print universal time in the same manner, just use `ZoneOffset.UTC` instead of `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.

To print military time, just use capital `H` instead of small `h` in the format pattern string, for example `"H:mm:ss"` for `16:20:01` or `"HHmm"` for `1620`. Capital `H` is for hour of day from 0 through 23, while `h` is for hour within AM or PM from 1 through 12. You can find all the letters you may use in a format pattern string in [the documentation of `DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).